# Django migrate error : TypeError expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn django and error occur in changing models. I tried a lot like default=datetime.datetime.now but I dont know how to fix it.

these are my models

from django.db import models
import datetime

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    introduction = models.TextField()
    area = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    party_number=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

class Poll(models.Model) :
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    area = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Choice(models.Model) :
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

when I type commmand : `python manage.py migrate`, this error occured

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, ang, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying ang.0003_poll_end_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 231, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 113, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 221, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 755, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1438, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1417, in get_prep_value
    value = super(DateTimeField, self).get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1275, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1378, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 93, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Maybe it should be `default=datetime.now` and not `default=datetime.datetime.now`?

Comment: i `import datetime` not `from datetime import datetime`

Comment: Are you modified the fields in models?

Comment: if modified,let me know which fields you modified?

Comment: I modified class Poll in start_date and end_date.
First time, it works successful but after I found that there was no () behind datetime in end_date. so I modified end_date, but later I modified almost everything. haha

Answer (score 11):

If you modified the fields in models. after that you run makemigrations that time it asking like this

```
^C(api_env)nyros@nyros:~/Desktop/santhi_projects/sample_api/sample_api$ python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'provider' to content without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 1
```

We select 1 option, then it will display like this

```
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> timezone.now()
```

We given timezone.now() then makemigrations completed.

See your migrations last file, there is

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ('providers', '0023_remove_content_provider'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='content',
        name='provider',
        field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='library', default=datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 7, 15, 12, 655838, tzinfo=utc), to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
]
```

In above code observe this line

```
default=datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 7, 15, 12, 655838, tzinfo=utc)
```

In that line forgeinkey field default value is datetime, Is it correct value?

No, so you have to give some string or object is a default value to that field.

Now you have to edit that value in that corresponding migration file, like this

```
default='some string'
```

then save and run the migrate command.

Try and let me know, Is it works or not.Thanks

Comment: I dont know what I should put in 'some string'. Can you show me some examples?

Comment: For example default = 123456.

Comment: Better to give some int value.

Comment: The first part of this answer worked for me, just entering timezone.now() after selecting option 1 was what was needed.

Answer (score 5):

Change your model field default value for `auto_now_add=True`

```
end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Not work :( Do you have any different suggestion for me?

Answer (score 4):

Remove your migrations with these commands :

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

Then delete database file with `rm db.sqlite`

Then run your server

Comment: If you have a virtualenv in `.` this will not turn out good

Answer (score 3):

Goto migration folder "`migrations`"

go to your migration file e.g`"0054_comment_date.py"`

change the `'default'` in line `field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=0)`

from 0 or whatevere is there

to `default='2012-09-04 06:00:00.000000-08:00`'

Answer (score 2):

Delete all the migrations manually. and  then type
*python manage.py makemigrations* and *python manage.py migrate*

-- Hope   this may work ..  worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all files in migrations folder except "init.py"
and delete "db.sqlite3" i.e your database and now make changes that you want and migrate.Hope This helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered with the same problem. The solution was to delete all default spaces in 'migrations' folder.

while you type 'python manage.py migrate' go up in terminal and find where the exact file in 'migrations' stopping the migrating. Then find all default arguments for DateField or DateTimeField and delete it. Those models don't handle with default argument.

```
migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='order',
        name='start_date',
        field=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, ***BUG default=False BUG***),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),
```

See the log in your terminal:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying ang.0003_poll_end_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
```

in this file there is a bug. Go there and delete the default argument from DateField

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `end_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` and it automatically creates a default date for you.
If this error not solved with this, then try deleting all your migrations. After this again use `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`, then migrate, it should definitely work.

I followed this and this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, when running through adding placeholders to my datefields, I accidentally entered "1" where "django.utils.timezone.now" should be, that is for the date-time default. Go into your last migration and find the "default=xxx" that is not like the rest and insert "django.utils.timezone.now"

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround may run ./manage.py migrate --fake

Answer (score 0):

In case all the above solutions do not work for you, like in my case. You can easy solve it with these simple steps.

1. Go into your apps directory and delete all previous migrations leaving only the

**pycache**
**init**.py

2. Go into your main project directory and delete the database. (NB: no side effect, please just do it)
3. With all done, open your terminal and run
   $ python manage.py makemigrations
   $ python manage.py migrate

Done. Thanks.

Comment: Please in the step 1, you will leave the __pycache__ folder and the __init__ .py. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just running:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

worked for me, I refer Suceel answer

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the instructions below you'll be good to have your error fixed.

1. `datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`
2. you will be provided with two options in which you have to choose option >> 1 *Provide the default...*
3. and then type `timezone.now`
4. and finally press enter

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted all my migrations and redid it. made it zero and re-migrated it all

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Look at all the models.DateTimeField lines in the .py file generated after calling makemigrations. There you will notice that some of the DateTimeField have a wrong default value. Replace those with models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=django.utils.timezone.now) for example.

Comment: The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.