# Error occurs during migrating the models in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make migrations when saving the models.py. I came across this error and I am at a complete loss. I am creating a database that saves all the employees details in an excel sheet. For instance, when any employee submits a file upload, all of the files will be saved to excel automatically.

**This is the error I came across.**

```
PS python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
PS python manage.py migrate      
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: EmpDBUpload, User, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying EmpDBUpload.0002_auto_20210715_1226...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\18050478\Desktop\Workspace\PCUpdated\PCUpdated\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\18050478\Desktop\Workspace\PCUpdated\PCUpdated\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 310, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 842, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1427, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1406, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1266, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1367, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Users\18050478\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**This is my models.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):  
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='EmpDB', null=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 
    EmpID = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    EmpName = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    EmpEmail = models.EmailField(null=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"File id: {self.id}"
```

**This is my forms.py**

```
class Employee(models.Model):  
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='EmpDB', null=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
 
    EmpID = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    EmpName = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    EmpEmail = models.EmailField(null=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"File id: {self.id}"
```

**Migrations file**

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.4 on 2021-07-15 04:28
 
from django.db import migrations, models
 
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
 
    dependencies = [
        ('EmpDBUpload', '0002_auto_20210715_1226'),
    ]
 
    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='uploaded',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True),
        ),
    ]
from django.db import migrations, models
 
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
 
    dependencies = [
        ('EmpDBUpload', '0001_initial'),
    ]
 
    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='econtact',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='eemail',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='eid',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='ename',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='activated',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='file_name',
            field=models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='EmpDB'),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='employee',
            name='uploaded',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=0),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

**The second one is 0002_auto_20210715_1226'**

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.4 on 2021-07-15 04:26
from django.db import migrations, models
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
dependencies = [
 ('EmpDBUpload', '0001_initial'),
 ]
operations = [
migrations.RemoveField(
model_name='employee',
name='econtact',
 ),
migrations.RemoveField(
model_name='employee',
name='eemail',
 ),
migrations.RemoveField(
model_name='employee',
name='eid',
 ),
migrations.RemoveField(
model_name='employee',
name='ename',
 ),
migrations.AddField(
model_name='employee',
name='activated',
field=models.BooleanField(default=False),
 ),
migrations.AddField(
model_name='employee',
name='file_name',
field=models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='EmpDB'),
 ),
migrations.AddField(
model_name='employee',
name='uploaded',
field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=0),
preserve_default=False,
 ),
 ]
```

Comment: Show us your migration file please.

Comment: It seems like there is an error with the datetime ``uploaded` according to the error. `match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`. Why are you putting `null=True` everywhere btw ?

Comment: I place null as the DB was asking me during Migration to provide a default value, which atm I do not have

Comment: Did this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355843/14457833

Comment: The default value of datetime field is not correct as per migration file..roll back migration and Please enter the default value during migration as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
>>> timezone.now()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your migration files shows that default is set to 0 for your DateTimeField. When parsing a DateTimeField object the parser expects a str object.

Try setting default to blank or some random string. Otherwise you can also use timezone.now()

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=now, null=True)
```